# im trying to insert data in mysql db from android

Tags: android, mysql

Please, I want someone to tell me what is wrong in my code, when I execute it, nothing happens in the database. I don't know there is an issue with my request or something else.

1. I have a table named expedition with columns: ide, bordereau, agenceorig, nomexped, numexped, nomdestin, numdestin, destination     emballage and valeur.
2. I have a form which gives me: $bordereau, $username, $nomexped, $numexped, $nomdestin, $numdestin, $destination, $emballage, $valeur
3. when I validate the form with a button, I check if $bordereau already exists with private function isexpedition($bordereau), and if it doesn't exist,  I insert the datas in  the table.

when I execute the code, I get this message: 
{"error":true,"message":"Une erreur est survenue, veillez recommencer"}, showing that datas haven't been inserted in the db.

```c
/*CRUD -> C -> CREATE*/
public function expedition($nomexped,$numexped,$nomdestin,$numdestin,$destination,$emballage,$bordereau,$valeur){
    if($this-> isexpedition($bordereau)){
        return 0;
    }else{

        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO expedition (ide,bordereau,agenceorig,nomexped,numexped,nomdestin,numdestin,destination,emballage,valeur) VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss",$Bordereau,$username,$Nomexped,$Numexped,$Nomdestin,$Numdestin,$Destination,$Emballage,$Valeur);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            return 1;    
        }else{
            return 2;
        }    
    }
}

private function isexpedition($bordereau){
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT ide FROM expedition WHERE bordereau=? ");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$bordereau);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    return $stmt->num_rows>0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which code? Impossible to help you.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: You should still edit your post to show clearly what you expect and what you get, explain the exact problem, according to the guidlines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Iadded more details. thank you for your help

Comment: Please use English.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username,password, email, gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $password, $email, $gender);

  //if the user is successfully added to the database 
  if($stmt->execute()){

  //fetching the user back 
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, id, username, email, gender FROM users WHERE username = ?"); 
  $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($userid, $id, $username, $email, $gender);
  $stmt->fetch();

  $user = array(
  'id'=>$id, 
  'username'=>$username, 
  'email'=>$email,
  'gender'=>$gender
  );

  $stmt->close();

  //adding the user data in response 
  $response['error'] = false; 
  $response['message'] = 'User registered successfully'; 
  $response['user'] = $user; 
  }
```